# Using Apigility on a remote server

Tags: laminas-api-tools

I have successfully installed Apigility to a remote CentOS server. It tell me to go to http://localhost:8888 to access the admin panel. This server does not have a GUI installed so I don't have the ability to remote in to use a web browser. Is there a workaround to access the Apigility interface remotely, possibly restricting access to my IP address? If not do I have to install it on my local machine and then deploy my work to the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

- You could add a [.htaccess
  file](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files--net-4757)
  to set a password on it
- If you're deploying to AWS you should be able to configure your SecurityGroup to only allow request to your installation if you're trying to access it.
- if you want to develop your application right now I would recommend to have a local installation in a docker container or so to perform your changes. If you're going live you shouldn't change anything in the admin surface either.

Answer (score 0):

centOS server using terminal if i am right. The best way to do this with centOs server in terminal is to open port 8888 to the public and access the server from another system ***serverIP:8888*** (using tools like firewalld in the centOs server. U will have to install firewalld) https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-open-a-port-in-centos-7-with-firewalld/